# What exit code 1 of linux jq means

Tags: jq, exit-code

As the tile says, I wonder when jq exits with code 1. In its manual, it says -e sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or null. Not clear what it means by the last output values of false or null? what if I don't use -e?

Comment: Basics first, When a command fails, it returns an non-zero exit code. If it succeeds, it returns zero. you can see this with basic code `true ; echo $? ; false ; echo $?`. I'm guessing that normally `jq` would only exit `1` if there was a syntax error or other errors (no file, etc) that keeps it from completing successfully. Using the `-e` option looks to be a way to extend that to "error-out" if there was not data returned. (false or null). IHTH

Comment: "What if i don't use -e", of course the best way to understand that is to try it yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The following is intended to supplement the information given about the -e option elsewhere on this page.

Assuming -e has NOT been specified, the return code is:

- 5 if a call to `error/1` or `halt_error/0` causes program termination
- an integral value (*) depending on N if `halt_error(N)` causes program termination, where N is a number; in particular, if N is non-negative, then the status is set to (N%256).

Otherwise, but still assuming -e has NOT been specified, the return code is:

- 2 if a parsing error reading input causes program termination
- 3 or 4 if a syntax error in the jq program causes program termination
- 0 on normal termination.

---

(*) Specifically:

`N % 256 | if . < 0 then 256+. else . end`

Comment: "Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran."
It looks like parsing errors return 4. I was testing it using jq 1.6. E.G.
echo '{"foo": [1 }' | jq .foo
echo $?
4

Comment: @F.G. - Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on current `jq` 1.6 source code from https://github.com/stedolan/jq

With `--exit-status` (`-e`), there are 6 possible exit codes:

- 0: jq output something and last line was neither false nor null
- 1: last line output was false or null
- 2: usage problem or system error
- 3: jq program compile error
- 4: jq didn't ouput anything at all
- 5: unknown (unexpected) error: any error other than 2 and 3

Without `--exit-status` (`-e`), 0 just means that `jq` ran successfully. Additionally, exit status 1 and 4 disappear and 0 is returned instead.

Here is (Unix Bourne shell) some ways to get 1 as an exit value:

```
$ echo false | jq -e .
false
$ echo '{ "foo": false }' | jq -e .foo
false

$ echo null | jq -e .
null
$ echo '{ "foo": null }' | jq -e .foo
null
$ echo '{ }' | jq -e .foo
null
$ echo '{ "foo": false }' | jq -e '.bar?'
null
```

Here is how to get 4:

```
$ echo 'false' | jq -e '.foo?'
```

And (I'm sure you want to know) here is one way to get 5:

```
$ echo false | jq .foo
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index boolean with string "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks quite comprehensive.